# What is the expected value of the product of randomly selected balls

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> An urn contains four balls numbered 1, 2, 5, and 7.  If a person
>   selects a set of two balls at random, what is the expected value of
>   the product of the numbers on the balls?

My thoughts:

$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}$

$E(X) = E_{1}(X)*E_{2}(X)$

The probability of choosing the first ball is $\frac{1}{4}$, so the expected value of the first ball is $E_{1}(X)=\tfrac{1}{4}\sum(1+2+5+7) = 3.75$

The probability of choosing the second ball is  $\frac{1}{3}$(because 3 balls left after the first move). But what would be the $E_{2}(X)$, since we don't know which ball was chosen first and can't say $E_{2}(X)=\tfrac{1}{4}\sum(2+5+7)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only 6 different ways to draw two balls, and each of those are equally likely, so I would just calculate it as:
$$
\frac{1\cdot 2+1\cdot 5+1\cdot 7+2\cdot 5+2\cdot 7+5\cdot 7}{6}
=\frac{2+5+7+10+14+35}{6}
=\frac{73}{6}
=12\frac{1}{6}
$$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by $E_1$ and $E_2$ but it is not true that
$$E[X] = E[X_1]E[X_2]$$
where $X_i$ is the value on the $i$th draw.

We can approach explicitly for clarity's sake (not efficiency):

\begin{array}{r|c|c|c|c}
 &1&2&5&7\\\hline
1&\mathsf X&2&5&7\\\hline
2&2&\mathsf X&10&14\\\hline
5&5&10&\mathsf X&35\\\hline
7&7&14&35&\mathsf X
\end{array}
Each cell that is not $\mathsf X$ has chance $(1/4)(1/3) = 1/12$.
Notice that the possible values of $X$ are $\mathscr K=\{2,5,7, 10,14,35\}$.
This implies the distribution of $X$ is
\begin{array}{c|c}
k&P(X=k)\\\hline
2&2/12\\\hline
5&2/12\\\hline
7&2/12\\\hline
10&2/12\\\hline
14&2/12\\\hline
35&2/12\\
\end{array}

Hence
$$E[X] = \sum_{k\in \mathscr K} kP(X = k) = \frac{73}{6}.$$

Comment: In your calculation of $E[X]$, it looks like you meant to write $$E[X] = \sum_{x \in \mathscr{K}} xP(X = x) = \frac{73}{6}$$

Comment: Yes, I meant $X = k$. Thanks.

Comment: For the sake of consistency, you should make that change in the table too.

Comment: Oh! Yes, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The expectation of a sum of random variables is always equal to the sum of expectations of the variables.   That is due to the *Linearity of Expectation*.

However, the expectation of a product of random variables is **not** *always* equal to the product of the expectation *unless* they are uncorrelated.   These random variables are *not* uncorrelated.

Instead you *can* use the tower property, also known as the *Law of Iterated Expectation*.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X_1{\cdot}X_2)=&~\mathsf E(X_1{\cdot}\mathsf E(X_2\mid X_1))\\[1ex]=&~ \mathsf E(X_1{\cdot}\tfrac13(15-X_1)) \\[1ex]=&~ 5\,\mathsf E(X_1)-\tfrac 13\,\mathsf E(X_1^2) \\[1ex]=&~ \tfrac{75}{4}-\tfrac 1{12}(1+4+25+49)\\[1ex]=&~ \tfrac{73}{6}\end{align}$$